# Python PIL import Mac compatiblity

Tags: python, image, macos, python-imaging-library

I wonder now for a long time, can I redirect python imports.
So on my Machine I did:

```
pip install pil
```

and then I can do:

```
from PIL import Image
```

That works great but the problem is many programs just want Image, they want:

```
import Image
```

Now my question is can I "redirect" the above statement so that I can use import Image?
If that does not work, how could I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can use any of the methods mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html).

On my linux installation, PIL already uses one of those - there's a directory called PILcompat which has files like Image.py, and a file called PILcompat.pth which is used to tell python to add this directory to its module search path. 
This way when

```
 import Image
```

is executed, python finds PILcompat/Image.py which executes its contents -

```
 from PIL.Image import *
```

I'm guessing either the .pth file or the directory are missing on your machine.